# jQuery UI - Adding a class to all selectmenus within div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to add a class to multiple Jquery UI selectmenu elements within a specific div. This seems to work fine on `<p>` elements but not on the jQuery UI elements.

In my example I'm trying to set the background color of the top 3 select menus to`#FF9999` but not the 4th. However, only the top select menu gets changed.

I use the same method for changing the color of the top 3 paragraphs to blue which does works.

I am using the `widget()` method to access the select menus that have been added through jQuery.

Here is my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m8dnczLu/

HTML

```
<div id="someID" class="someClass">
  <div class="someOtherClass">
    <p id="p1">Paragraph 1</p>
    <select>
      <option value="0">Hello 1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="someOtherClass">
    <p id="p2">Paragraph 2</p>
    <select>
      <option value="0">Hello 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="someOtherClass">
    <p id="p3">Paragraph 3</p>
    <select>
      <option value="0">Hello 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="someID2">
  <p id="p4">Paragraph 4</p>
  <select>
    <option value="0">Hello 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bClass {
  color: blue;
}
.rClass {
  background: #FF9999;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('select').selectmenu();
$('#someID select').selectmenu('widget').addClass('rClass');
$('#someID p').addClass('bClass');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `widget` method only returns the button from the first menu. You need to loop over all the menus to do this.

```
$("#someID select").each(function() {
    $(this).selectmenu("widget").addClass('rClass');
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/m8dnczLu/3/)